# What are good resources to study the historic evolution and comparative studies of Abhidhamma

Tags: reference-request, history, early-buddhism

What are good resources and references (ideally online) to learn historic evolution of Abhidhamma. Also comparative studies on different Abhidhamma schools.

*NB: I am aware of BPU BPhil 3rd Year Lecture Notes. So I am looking for resource other than this.*

Comment: Perhaps this may be of use to you? http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/abhidhamma.pdf

Answer (score 1):

***Hope this helps.***

[Abhidhamma Studies III: Origins of the Canonical Abhidha(r)mma Literature](http://jocbs.org/index.php/jocbs/article/view/108)

Abhidhamma Studies: Buddhist Explorations of Consciousness and Time;
and Abhidhamma Studdies--Introduction, both by Ven. Nyanaponika Thera

Studies in Abhidhamma Literature and the Origins of Buddhist Philoposhical Systems by Erich Frauwaller. At Sunypress.edu

*Similar books and/or articles:*

Karl H. Potter (1970). Abhidharma Buddhism to 150 A.D.

In The Encyclopedia of Indian Philosophies. Motilal Banarsidass
Chandra B. Varma (1992).

A Concise Encyclopedia of Early Buddhist Philosophy: Based on the Study of the Abhidhammatthasaṅgahasarūpa. Eastern Book Linkers.
Jay Garfield, Translation as Transmission and Transformation.
C. L. A. De Silva (1937/1988).

A Treatise on Buddhist Philosophy, or, Abhidhamma. Sri Satguru Publications.
Gustav Roth (ed.) (2009).

Stupa: Cult and Symbolism. Aditya Prakashan.
H. W. Bailey (ed.) (2010).

Buddhist Poetry, Thought, and Diffusion. International Academy of Indian Culture and Aditya Prakashan.
Richard King (1998).

Vij Aptim Trat and the Abhidharma Context of Rarly Yog C Ra. Asian Philosophy 8 (1):5 – 17.
Noa Ronkin (2005).

Early Buddhist Metaphysics: The Making of a Philosophical Tradition. London ; New Yorkroutledgecurzon.
Herbert V. Guenther (1976).

Philosophy and Psychology in the Abhidharma. Distributed by Random House.
Eli Franco (2004).

The Spitzer Manuscript: The Oldest Philosophical Manuscript in Sanskrit. Verlag Der Österreichischen Akademie Der Wissenschaften.